# How to make a NAS server visible to the network, while it is connected to PC?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, nas

Right now I have following configuration:

> NAS (192.168.177.2) -> PC (192.168.177.1; 192.168.1.100) ->
>   TL-WR1043ND (192.168.1.1) -> Internet

The whole thing works in terms of NAS being able to access internet:
PC has its internet connection shared and NAS is able to update, etc.
But when it gets to DLNA server which is on NAS, it is only visible to PC, the rest things connected directly to router are not able to see the DLNA broadcast.

And that is exactly what I need: so that NAS is visible to all items in the general router subnet.

Comment: What is wrong with attaching the NAS to the router with a wired connection?

Comment: Right now router is in a closet, where NAS will most likeley overheat. That will change sometime after, but for now the issue stands :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLNA broadcasts do what broadcast do - they reach every device on the **same** network. Your PC will be able to see the DLNA broadcast, but no other device will.

The solution would be to bridge both network interfaces on your PC - this can be done by selecting both interfaces in the network control panel, rightclick and select bridge on Windows, and with a little more work on Linux, depending on your specific settings, distribution and so on.

Bridging will essentially make your NAS be part of the 192.168.1.0 network, so it can get an address via DHCP from your TP-Link, or you may set a static IP in the 192.168.1.0 network manually. This should enable access for all devices on your local network.

Comment: But wouldn't bridging disable the PC connection to router, i.e. the PC would loose internet acces?

Comment: No, it won't. The PC will simply have one logical network interface, which just happens to has two ports. Or think of it as your two network cards become a mini network switch, with your PC, the NAS and the router connected to it. Just make sure that bridging interface gets an 1920168.1.x IP address, either using DHCP or by manual configuration.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Bridged them and now it appeared in all LAN devices.

Comment: Great ;-) if you mark my answer as accepted, everybody can see that this question is solved and requires no further attention. :-)